# Refreshing SVG in Illustrator after editing in VS Code

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I have a SVG which I have opened in Visual Studio Code and in Adobe Illustrator at the same time.

I am using VS Code to edit the markup. I was wondering if there is a way for me to refresh the svg in Illustrator to see the effect of the edit that I made in the markup. Is there a refresh button in illustrator that lets me do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Not if you **opened** the SVG in Illustrator. Once opened, the file is assumed to be live and AI doesn't speak with the file system any further until you save or manually request interaction. **Opened** artwork is sort of in a "suspended" state - It does *not* reference the file on disk in terms of "reading" at any point once loaded into AI.

You *could try* the `Revert` command in the File menu... that *might work*. AI will close the open document and then reopen it from the file on disk. That may cause the loss of any additional information in the AI file if you'd edited there as well.

** -- I make no guarantees that using `Revert` *won't* lose data. It might -- **

---

If you wish to "refresh" an object in Illustrator it **must** be a **link**. You can then refresh the **link** via the **Links Panel**. Linked files can not be edited as "live" artwork in Illustrator.

**Unfortunately**, it appears as though Illustrator simply **won't** link to an SVG file. When you "place" an SVG into AI, the art is embedded by default. There appears to be no option to "link" to the original SVG file. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to look into this. I was trying to use Place as you mentioned. Please correct me if I am wrong and I am desperately hoping that I am wrong. When you place a raster image using place the link is established. But when you place svg using Place the link is grayed out meaning the refresh option in link panel is grayed out. Place would work for me if the refresh is activated on the link panel for svg.

Comment: Hi @smpa01 -- You're right. I never noticed that before. Sorry for leading you astray. You can't "link" to an SVG. AI merely embeds the SVG by default. You could do some workaround... which may be **more trouble than they are worth possibly**... Place Linked SVG into Photoshop. Save as PSD... place PSD into AI as link... then edit SVG, update link in PS, save, then refresh link in AI. -- Like I've posted, way more trouble. And I don't know if it's even worth it to you. Very odd.. since you *can* link an AI file inside another AI file.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: @smpa01 for what its wirth it works with EPS fies.